# MacAfee AV Removal Trouble

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus

Has anybody had a difficult time removing MacAfee AV software? I tried removing it from the control panel and it says I am not allowed to remove this program at this time?

Comment: McAfee is malware and hard to remove.....;-)

Comment: @Moab This is not really constructive as it is legitimate software.

Comment: Legitimate malware.

Answer (score 1):

#### I tried removing it from the control panel

> and it says I am not allowed to remove this program at this time?

Use the McAfee Consumer Product Removal tool (MCPR). Instruction below.

---

#### How to uninstall supported McAfee products using the Consumer Products Removal tool

> Intel Security recommends that you uninstall your McAfee home user
>   products using the Windows removal methods shown below. If you are not
>   able to remove your products in this way, go to Step 2.
>
> 1. Use the appropriate procedure depending on the version of Windows you have installed:
>
>    - Windows 10: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/repair-or-remove-programs#v1h=tab01
>    - Windows 8, 8.1: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/uninstall-change-program
>    - Windows 7 or Vista: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uninstall-change-program#uninstall-change-program=windows-7
> 2. Download and run the McAfee Consumer Product Removal (MCPR) tool:
>
>    a) Download the MCPR tool from
>      http://us.mcafee.com/apps/supporttools/mcpr/mcpr.asp and save it
>      to a temporary folder on your computer.
>
>    IMPORTANT: Because the MCPR tool is updated periodically, always download a new copy before each use.
>
>    b)   Navigate to the folder where you saved the file, and double-click MCPR.exe.
>
>    c)   If you see a User Account Control dialog box, click Yes.
>
>    d)   At the McAfee Software Removal screen, click Next.
>
>    e)   At the End User License Agreement (EULA) dialog box, click Next
>      to accept the agreement.
>
>    f)   When prompted, type the Captcha information exactly as seen (it
>      is case-sensitive) and then click Next.
>
>    NOTE: This step minimizes accidental executions of MCPR.
>
>    g)   If you have Family Protection installed, you will need to follow these steps. Otherwise, continue to Step h.
>
>    - Type your Family Protection Administrator name and Password, then click Next.
>    - If authentication fails, follow the on-screen instructions to obtain an uninstall code.
>
>    h)   When you see the message CleanUp Successful, restart your
>      computer because your McAfee product will not be fully removed until
>      after the restart.
>
>    IMPORTANT: If you see the message Cleanup Unsuccessful, save your MCPR log files for analysis by Technical Support:
>
>    - At the Cleanup Unsuccessful dialog box, click View Logs. Your troubleshooting log will open in a Notepad window.
>    - Click File, Save As, and save the file to your Desktop. Name the file MCPR_date.txt (for example, MCPR_Jan10_16.txt).
>    - Contact McAfee Technical Support and provide the log file to your technician for troubleshooting.
>
>    i)   Confirm that all
>      McAfee products have been removed from your computer.

Source [How to uninstall or re-install supported McAfee products using the Consumer Products Removal tool](https://service.mcafee.com/webcenter/portal/cp/home/articleview?locale=en-US&articleId=TS101331&fromSearch=true&platform=pc&_afrLoop=579872007435482#!%40%40%3F_afrLoop%3D579872007435482%26articleId%3DTS101331%26centerWidth%3D100%2525%26fromSearch%3Dtrue%26leftWidth%3D0%2525%26locale%3Den-US%26platform%3Dpc%26rightWidth%3D0%2525%26showFooter%3Dfalse%26showHeader%3Dfalse%26_adf.ctrl-state%3Dm3otlxlp7_196)